# How can I prove this theorem about quadratic matrix inequalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Given the real matrices $A$ and $B = B^T$, how can I show that there exists a real matrix $C$ such that $AC + C^T A^T + C^T C \leq B$ if and only if $B + AA^T \geq 0$?

For the "only if" part, what I tried is as follows: Because $AC + C^T A^T + C^T C \leq B$, then there exists a positive semi-definite matrix $Q$ such that $AC + C^T A^T + C^T C + Q = B$. This almost looks like an algebraic Riccati equation in $C$, except the $C^T A^T$ term should be $CA^T$. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $B+AA^T\ge0$, then $AC+C^TA^T+C^TC\le B$ when $C=-A^T$.

Conversely, if $AC+C^TA^T+C^TC\le B$, then
$$
B+AA^T\ge AC+C^TA^T+C^TC+AA^T=(A+C^T)(A+C^T)^T\ge0.
$$

Comment: This is a very slick proof. How did you know to set $C = -A^T$ in the first part? I'm thinking of something like $$\begin{align} B + AA^T &\geq 0 \\ B &\geq -AA^T \\ &= -AA^T - AA^T + AA^T \end{align}$$ and then setting $C = -A^T$, but I'm not sure if this is how you approached this.

Comment: @mhdadk Yes, that was what I thought.